# How can I extract data from a text file and import into new output file?

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

Assume the following is the data in ctf_output.txt, I would like to extract title headings from Rod #, Surface Temp and Centerline Temp, and then only the highest temperature for each and for each rod.  Notice I put specific and significantly higher temps in each column with no repeats.

```
Rod 1  
Surface Temperature Centerline Temperature  
500         510    
501         511  
502         512  
503         513  
504         525  
505         515  
535         516  
507         517  
508         518  
509         519  
510         520  
Rod 2  
Surface Temperature   Centerline Temperature  
500               510  
501           511  
502           512  
503           513  
504           555  
505           515  
540           516  
507               517  
508           518  
509           519  
510           520  
Rod 3
Surface Temperature   Centerline Temperature  
500           510  
501           511  
502           512  
503           513  
567           514  
505           515  
506           559  
507           517  
508           518  
509           519  
510           520
```

How can I do this with python?  I need a python script that will pull the data and populate a new output file with a format of:

```
Rod 1  
Surface Temperature Centerline Temperature  
535         525  

Rod 2  
Surface Temperature   Centerline Temperature  
540           555  

Rod 3  
Surface Temperature   Centerline Temperature  
567           559
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd read the file line by line, then keep track of the maxima and output those when the next section begins:

```
with open('ctf_output.txt', 'r') as temps, open(outputfilename, 'w') as output:
    surface_max = centerline_max = None
    for line in temps:
        if line.startswith('Rod'):
            # start of new section
            if surface_max is not None or centerline_max is not None:
                # write maximum for previous section
                output.write('{}\t\t\t{}\n\n'.format(surface_max, centerline_max))
            # write out this line and the next to the output file
            output.write(line)
            output.write(next(temps, ''))
            # reset maxima
            surface_max = centerline_max = 0
        elif line.strip():
            # temperature line; read temperatures and track maxima
            surface, centerline = [int(t) for t in line.split()]
            if surface > surface_max:
                surface_max = surface
            if centerline > centerline_max:
                centerline_max = centerline
    if surface_max or centerline_max:
        # write out last maxima
        output.write('{}\t\t\t{}\n'.format(surface_max, centerline_max))
```

The output uses 3 tabs, just like your input.

For your example input, this writes:

```
Rod 1  
Surface Temperature Centerline Temperature  
535         525

Rod 2  
Surface Temperature   Centerline Temperature  
540         555

Rod 3
Surface Temperature   Centerline Temperature  
567         559
```

Comment: Great! But you missed one parenthesis in the first output.write (line 8).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up; fixed.